# Wi-Fi shows all bars but data can only be transferred after a delay

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wifi-transfer

I noticed that for the first 30 seconds to a minute of having connected to school Wi-Fi, although the Wi-Fi icons shows that Wi-Fi is connected, no data is transferred. Nothing can be loaded and if I have an internet speed test preloaded the speed is shown as `0.00`:

[image: Speed]

My questions are:

- Why does the Wi-Fi say there's a connection when for all intents and purposes there isn't?
- Why is there a long delay between when data can actually be loaded and between when the computer is ostensibly connected to Wi-Fi?

Comment: Your school network may be doing some actions after you've connected. Only your schools IT dept may be able give some details as to what's going on and what you may be able to do to minimize this delay.

Answer (score 2):

Wi-Fi being connected is a local connection between you and the router/access point, this doesn't say anything about what the router/access point is doing/allowing/capable/connected.

Wi-Fi is like the wire from your device to the local network, nothing more.

The speed test is a test of what you can download and upload to/from the outside internet (World Wide Web) and it seems that your school Wi-Fi either has a very limited (low Bandwidth) connection to the internet, or has something set on it to limit speed.

(To note, if you can load Google to get to the Speed Test you obviously are connected, even to the internet. But the speed might be too slow to get the speed test going.)

Comment: The speedtest window was already open.

Comment: From when you were connected to a different internet connection? In that case, I'd say that most likely when you did this Speed Test you weren't (yet) connected by the school's Wi-Fi system to the "internet" at all.

Comment: If I am remembering correctly, whenever I close and reopen my laptop, it seems show as being connected reasonably fast, but then it actually takes a very long time to be usefully connected in a way that can actually download data. And since the computer thinks there is a connection, the browsers just load forever trying in vain to download data from a useless connection instead of immediately failing due to a complete lack of a connection. The question is why are there these fake connections?